# How to get wordpress custom fields rss feed into zend?

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework, rss

My web site is based on zend framework that have wordpress blog. I want to get new post details in the site. Using zend **Zend_Feed_Reader** [function](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.reader.html) I can get title, link, description ... But there is no method to get wordpress custom fields feed. 
Is there any existing method or any other way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include `wp-load.php` in your zend site.  This will give you access to everything in wordpress (functions, posts, meta) and you won't have to go out and retrieve an RSS feed to get it.